# Having an -ing with an object in a sentence

Tags: gerunds

I was told that ing can be used without an object e.g "the manager forbids smoking" while I know this is true, I want to ask if it can also be used with objects e.g., "I love making lasagne" or " the manager forbids smoking in his establishment." can the ing form be used like this also?

Comment: Why do you think not? See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: "smoking" or "smoking in his establishment" can be the object of the verb *forbids*.

Comment: "Lasagne" is direct object of "making". Your other two examples are strictly speaking ambiguous since "smoking" could be a verb or a noun, though verb preferred. Noun interpretation can be forced with adjectival premodification, as in The manager forbids even occasional smoking". And "in his establishment" is not direct object, but an adjunct.

Comment: The reason I asked was because my teacher used said we can use ing without an object and infinitive with objects so I was kinda confused about it. But since you all said it's ok, I'm more confident to use it with or without objects.

Comment: The manager forbids smoking weed.

Answer (score 1):

The Ving(Gerund) can be followed by an object or not, it is based on the context. For example, I stopped smoking. (In this sentence, the Gerund Ving is the direct object of the verb "stopped").
In your sentence: The manager forbids smoking in his establishment. (In this case, the Ving (smoking) is the direct object of the verb "forbids" and the phrase "in his establishment" is adverbial of this sentence, not the object, and this is correct in grammar.

Comment: Or you can look upon "...smoking in his establishment" as an object clause.